# How can I add a context menu extension for the root directory?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, context-menu

To add an option `Open with FolderSize` to the Explorer context menu I added the following key to the registry:

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Open with FolderSize]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Open with FolderSize\command]
>   @="\"C:\FileUtils\FolderSize\FolderSize.exe\" %1"

This works, but not for the root directory, like `C:\`. How can I add the option for the root as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\Open with FolderSize]

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.